# Entourage.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have added [entourage.js](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/58-entourage-js-automatic-download-tracking-for-asynchronous-google-analytics) on a [website](http://www.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk/scripts/entourage.js) to automatically track any file downloads like .doc,.pdf files etc but it does not seem to track any thing. I have the following code in the head section of the website

```
<script src="/scripts/entourage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-xx']);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 (function () {
     var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
     ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

    </script>
```

Any ideas why

Comment: Could you give me a page from the website where i can download a file?

Comment: looks like google analytics code, doesn't it?

Comment: sure the link is http://techoctave.com/entourage/

Comment: @ekremkrc, entourage plugs into analytics.

Comment: @Dev I mean on your site.

Comment: The website is http://www.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk

Comment: @Dev, I know, I mean a page that has a direct link to download a file that should be tracked.

Comment: Sorry, this page has .doc file link on the page http://www.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk/helpandtraining/help-and-training/about-the-knowledge-network-.aspx

Comment: Any input guys? thanks